# Power Query Как пронумеровать повторы/ дубликаты

Tags: excel, скрипт, формулы, таблицы

Пример:
Яблоко    1
Яблоко    2
Груша     1
Груша     2
Арбуз     1
Дыня      1

Есть столбик таблицы с наименованиями, нужно пронумеровать повторы, то есть при уникальных значениях всегда будет стоять 1, а если дубли есть то они подписываются 2,3,4 и т.д.
Делая в Power Query, пробола многие варианты, и из форума тоже - результатов пока нет.
БУду благодарна за помощ!

Comment: Добро пожаловать в SO! Как насчёт индекса в группе: сортируем, группируем, добавляем `Indexed = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {{"Rows", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_,"GroupIndex", 1, 1)}})` и опять разворачиваем? Это [**здесь**](http://datacornering.com/how-to-create-group-index-with-power-query-or-r/)

Comment: Формулы листа принимаются? Метка указана...`=СЧЕТЕСЛИ(A$2:A2;A2)`